# How to find the domain of a function such that it will be all positive numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I've been working on this problem for a while now and I feel like I'm not understanding it:

Find all numbers a such that the domain of the function:

$$f(x)= {1\over\sqrt{1+2ax-x^2}}$$

Contains all positive numbers.

So far I have tried to use the quadratic formula to find where the function is negative and where the function is positive but without a set constant for "a" I have not been able to achieve this. If anyone could walk me through this It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no $a$ in your expression.

Comment: I don't believe any $a$ works, actually.

Comment: I know the answer is that, but how do you prove it?

Answer (score 2):

$1+2ax-x^2 = (1 + a^2)-(x - a)^2$.

So $1+2ax-x^2 = -1$ when $x = \sqrt{a^2 + 2} + a$

$\sqrt{a^2 + 2} + a$ is a positive number for all $a$.

Hence $x = \sqrt{a^2 + 2} + a > 0$ will never be in the domain of $f$.

Comment: The question states that the domain of $f(x)$ should contain (at least) all positive numbers. This does not exclude complex numbers.

Comment: @fibonatic. Nonsense. Unless otherwise stated, we are dealing with real numbers.

Comment: You are right, I confused domain with range.

Answer (score 0):

This function is defined if and only if $-x^{2}+2x+1>0$ or euivalently, $x^{2}-2x-1<0$. The discriminant is $2^{2}-4(-1)=8$, so it has two real distinct roots $x_{1}<x_{2}$, which you determine by the uadrtic formula. f is defined on $]x_{1},x_{2}[$.

Comment: I still don't see how this will help me solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well the numerator is obviously always positive so for the whole thing to be positive we just need the denominator to be positive so:
$$\sqrt{1+2x-x^2} > 0$$

$$1+2x-x^2 > 0$$

From here you just use the quadratic formula and figure out when the $function = 0$ and then you can figure out when its greater than $0$ from the $0$s

Also Calculus is not a good tag for this question